# Can someone look at this python loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a loop that lists all of the MLB teams by abbreviation. If I take "team" out the code, it works as designed. However, when I add "team = team[i]" the code malfunctions and returns "r" instead of the second team on my list, ATL. I have a feeling that the code is looking at the second letter of "ARI", my first team. I need to have "team" equal the abbreviation after every loop for a second web-scraping program. If someone can figure out how to do that, I will be forever grateful!

My MLB list is ordered as such:
ari,
atl,
bal,
bos,
cws,
chc,
cin,
cle,
col,
det,
hou,
kc,
ana,
la,
mia,
mil,
min,
nym,
nyy,
oak,
phi,
pit,
sd,
sf,
sea,
stl,
tb,
tex,
tor,
was,
break

My code is:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time


#Bringing list of teams over

wb = load_workbook(filename = "MLBTeams.xlsx", data_only=True)
sheet=wb['Teams']

loc = 'a1' #starting location
team = [] #list of names 

print("running")

#while the location of sheet is not null
while sheet[loc].value != "break":
    team.append(sheet[loc].value) #adding all the names to a list
    l2 = loc.split('a')
    num = int(l2[1])
    num = num + 1
    loc = 'a' + str(num)
    


i = 0
while team[i] != None: 
    #team = team[i]
    print(team[i] + " started")
    outputname = str(team[i]) + "data.csv" 
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n On to the next one \n")
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: `team = team[i]` replaces `team` by its `i`th item, so how would the code make sense after that?

Comment: I am using that part of the code to cycle through all of the team names, so I am hoping that team[i+1] = my second team, team[i+2] = the third and so on.

Comment: Use a new variable `thisteam = team[i]`  for example

Comment: Kendle, you saint! Thank you so much!

Comment: mind sharing your MLBTeams.xlsx file. You are slightly over complicating this.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the last block with

```
for thisTeam in team: 
    print(thisTeam + " started")
    outputname = str(thisTeam) + "data.csv" 
    time.sleep(1)
    # call a function or do other stuff here
    print("\n On to the next one \n")
```